# how i can solve "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException" error?

Tags: java, ant, shibboleth

I am trying to install shibboleth IDP in ubuntu
I got this error while trying to apply a script
do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?
note that i install OpenJDK version "11.0.11"
and i use these libraried libmariadb-java,libcommons-dbcp-java, libcommons-pool-java

could you help me in finding the solution?

the error:
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:389)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:690)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:797)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:783)
at net.shibboleth.idp.installer.InstallerSupport.createDirectory(InstallerSupport.java:66)
at net.shibboleth.idp.installer.CopyDistribution.copyDist(CopyDistribution.java:138)
at net.shibboleth.idp.installer.CopyDistribution.execute(CopyDistribution.java:68)
at net.shibboleth.idp.installer.ant.impl.V4InstallTask.execute(V4InstallTask.java:91)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:830)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:190)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:274)

Comment: Check the installation instructions, and see what they say about whether you need to be `root` to install the software.

Comment: really thanks for helping, i appreciate your efforts